# Why doesn't my SDL2 code display images with SDL_Texture*

Tags: c++

I have a C++  project where I'm initially trying to display a PNG image to the screen.

This is my code.

RenderWindow.hpp

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

class RenderWindow
{

public:
    RenderWindow(const char *p_title, int p_width, int p_height);
    void render();
    void cleanUp();

private:
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load("~/SDL2_Game/images/Green_Tile.png");
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image);
};
```

RenderWindow.cpp

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "RenderWindow.hpp"

RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const char* p_title, int p_w, int p_h):window(NULL), renderer(NULL)
{

window = SDL_CreateWindow(p_title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, p_w, p_h, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
if (window == NULL) std::cout << "Window failed to init: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
}
void RenderWindow::render(){
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
//SDL_Rect dstrect = { 5, 5, 320, 240 };
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
void RenderWindow::cleanUp(){
SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
SDL_FreeSurface(image);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "RenderWindow.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
    std::cout << "Problem with initialization. " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
    std::cout << "Initialization success!" <<std::endl;
    }
    if (!IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG)){
     std::cout << "Problem with Image initialization " <<SDL_GetError() << std::endl;  
       
    }
    
RenderWindow win("RPG_Game_v_1.0", 800, 600);
win.render();
bool gameRunning = true;
SDL_Event event;

while(gameRunning){
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) gameRunning = false;
}
}

win.cleanUp();
IMG_Quit();
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

I'm on a Linux machine.

I compile this with

```
 g++ -g -o game ./*.cpp -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

Only a window is displaying. There is no image. I've tried refactoring my code with SDL_BlitSurface() and it does indeed display the PNG image. But why is this code not working? is it due to the fact that I'm using SDL_Texture* and my current system does not have a discrete graphics card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the call to `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` fails because it is called before `SDL_CreateWindow` and `SDL_CreateRenderer`, thereby initializing `texture` to `NULL`.

Please move the initizalization of `texture` (and `image`) to after `window` and `renderer` are initialized.

To further help with such issues, please check if the result of SDL functions != `NULL` and print `SDL_GetError()` to get more information about what went wrong.

Comment: I coped it into a new file and tried calling it in the order you specified.

You were correct. For some reason, both the image and texture are returning NULL.
_Couldn't open ~/SDL2_Game/images/Green_Tile.png
SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface() passed NULL surface._
Why these are returning NULL?

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I moved the image to the same folder and it works! Thanks.

Comment: I changed from an absolute path to a relative path. Now it is working everywhere. The order of calling functions is important. Thanks.